# Parentheses become encoded in codeigniter db query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a legacy database with a field which contains some parentheses, like "red(b)".

But if I try to query for that value, the parentheses come out encoded.

This query:

```
select * from table where field1 = "red(b)"
```

Becomes this query:

```
select * from table where field1 = "red & #40; b & #41; "
```

(I put a space between the & and # so it would show).

This return no rows.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Nick, thank for your help.

As it turned out, the encoding took place between routing.php and my controller.  So all I had to do was reverse it at the controller to eliminate the encoded parentheses.  The query is working great now.

Comment: I have the same problem too.. how did you do that? routing.php?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the query? i.e.

```
select * from table where field1 = "red\(b\)"
```